# How can I check the existence of several subfolders

Tags: shell

I have several folders with 4 letters, all of them have the same subfolders (`joint`), and in each of these subfolders there might be the folder `01`, `02` and `all`. What I want to do is enter all 4-letter-folders and subsequent `joint` folder and see if there is a `02` folder in it or not. If there is it should give me the contents of the `all` folder, if it does not, it should show me the contents of the `01` folder

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
  
dir=$(pwd)

for folder in ????

do

cd "$folder" || exit

cd joint

if [ -d "/$dir/$folder/joint/02" ]; then
       cd all || exit
fi

if [ ! -d "/$dir/$folder/joint/02" ]; then
       cd 01 || exit
fi

ls

cd ../../..

done
```

so it would look something like this

```
1234
 joint
    ├── 01
    ├── 02
    └── all
```

What I am getting is that the code is running only through one of the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

You will probably have to adopt the inner most if-then-else to fit your needs.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# for all files in the curent dir
for d in `ls -1`; do
    
    # if it is a directory
    if [ -d $d ]; then
    
        # if there is a sub directory "joint"
        if [ -d $d/joint ]; then
        
            # if there is a further sub dir "joint/02"
            if [ -d $d/joint/02 ]; then
                
                # then list the files in $d/joint/all/
                echo "files in $d/joint/all/"
                ls -l $d/joint/all/
            else
                # otherwise list the files in $d/joint/01/
                echo "files in $d/joint/01/"
                ls -l $d/joint/01/
            fi
        fi
    fi 
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, is there a way to only display the files and not the size, name of the user and other informations, such as it is now?
e.g. `-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 miro  staff  66300 18 Set 11:51 STLZ.eps`

Comment: @MiroFeliciano Yes. If you dont use `ls -l` but instead only `ls` you will get only the file names.

If you want further details, open a terminal an enter `man ls`. It will display the man page of `ls`. (You may leave it pressing `q`.)

An alternative to get some more infos about the options of a program is to add `--help` as the first option to the program. Try `ls --help` in a terminal.